# New sandbox with default values

Tags: community, sandbox

I would like to create new sandbox instance but I need it to be created with default values. What I mean by default values is that when new sandbox is created in Salesforce it is making a copy and is using the data from the production instance. I would like to avoid that by creating a brand new clean sandbox with no or with default data.

Could you please advise how this can be achieved?

Regards,

Dilyan

Answer (score 5):

Yes, create a new DE org. A Sandbox is intended to mimic your production org, not a brand new "clean" org. You could still deploy something to production using Eclipse or the Migration Toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

A dev sandbox is the way to go, as @crmprogdev stated. You could even create a sandbox template if you want only specific objects created in your sandbox.